# how to connect adb to andyroid

Tags: android, shell

**andyroid** is a new android emulator that is very fast and it's simple to work with it... i want to use it and connect `adb` to it ... i know for connecting `adb` to emulators like `bluestack` i should type `adb connect x.x.x.x` in cmd.... andyroid usually is connects via this ip : `192.168.x.y`... i tried to connect to it several times... but i got this :

```
D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 192.168.x.y
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.x.y:5555

D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
```

how can i connect to it ?...

Comment: what `adb devices` command is showing? Have you enabled debuging in developer options?

Comment: @KarolŻygłowicz it's empty : `adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
`.. but one time i could connect to it and try some commands....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enabled debuggind in developer options i guess you dont have right drivers on your pc, and instaling them could be tricky. For example with real phones you need drivers similar to for example this one 
http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

Comment: why tricky?... so why it's simple and easy about `Bluestack` ... but about this one i got problem??... and one time i could do that....

Comment: its tricky because you don't know what driver you need. I had problem like you with real phone. I downloaded driver that people sugest in the internet. This driver failed when was 50% of instalation process, but that was enaught to make my phone visible in adb.

Comment: so how can i find all shell command to execuse in `adb shell` ??

Comment: `adb help` shows all adb commands. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: yes.. thanks.... .. another question... if i want to use `sqlite3` in cmd when i'm connected to a real phone, it's possible or? or should i install it first??

Comment: AFAIC all phones run sqlite above version 3 and according to this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html there is no other command to open sqlite, i believe you dont need to install anything.. but this is another question and off topic for this one